# Problems with score function in corona sdk (lua)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Good evening,
I have a problem with the score function in my videogame.
I need it for a university exam.
in practice, in the video game the little man has to "save" the animals from the burning forest and jump over the sotacles.
when he goes on an animal the score increases, only that the score doubles and, after he has saved the first animal, the other elements invert the typical direction of travel. it almost seems that the little man pushes him in the opposite direction.

What could be the problem?

here the codes with the score function and the generation of the elements

```
local function updateScore()
scoreDisplay=display.newText(sceneGroup, "Score:", display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY-150, native.systemFont, 30)
scoreDisplay:setFillColor(black)
score = score + 1
scoreDisplay.text="Score:" .. score 
end 

-- Funzione per la creazione degli ostacoli e animali 
local function createElement( event )
    
-- In base al numero cambia l'elemento caricato
local obstacle = math.random(4)

-- Ostacolo fiamma 
if(obstacle == 1) then
element = display.newImageRect(sceneGroup,"img/flame.png", 80, 80);
element.myName = "obstacle"
            
-- L'elemento generato viene posizionato in modo casuale, ma entro i margini dello schermo
element.x = 1080
element.y = 100;
-- Aggiungiamo un corpo statico alla fiamma 
        
physics.addBody(element, "dynamic", { bounce=0.0 })
        
-- Ostacolo roccia 
elseif(obstacle == 2) then
element = display.newImageRect(sceneGroup,"img/rock.png", 70, 50);
element.myName = "obstacle"
            
element.x = 1080
element.y = 100;
-- Aggiungiamo un corpo statico alla roccia
    
physics.addBody(element, "dynamic", { bounce=0.0 })
        
-- Animale 
elseif (obstacle == 3) then
        
element = display.newImageRect(sceneGroup,"img/rabbit.png", 80, 80);
element.myName = "animal"
    
element.x = 1080
element.y = 100;
-- Aggiungiamo un corpo statico al coniglio 
        
physics.addBody(element, "dynamic", { bounce=0.0 })   
        
elseif (obstacle==4) then 
element = display.newImageRect(sceneGroup,"img/koala.png", 200, 120);
element.myName = "animal"
         
element.x = 1080
element.y = 100;
        
-- Aggiungiamo un corpo statico al koala 
        
physics.addBody(element, "dynamic", { bounce=0.0 })
end 
    
table.insert(elements, element)
return element   
end 

-- funzione che elimina gli ostacoli non attivi e ne crea di nuovi
-- e viene chiamato ogni secondo
```

and here the collision function

```
--funzione che implementa le collisioni     
local function onCollision(self,event)
if (event.phase=="began") then
-- self rappresenta l'oggetto badGuy
-- event.other rappresenta l'altro ogetto
-- coinvolto nell'urto
    
if event.other.myName=="ground" and event.contact.isTouching==true then
self.action="run"
end 

if ((event.other.myName=="animal" and self.myName=="boy") or (event.other.myName=="animal" and self.myName=="boy")) then
if(event.contact.isTouching==true) then 
updateScore()
end 
event.contact.isTouching=false
transition.fadeOut( event.other, { time = 30 } )
print("score")
end 
end 

--se la collisione avviene tra boy, la fiamma e la roccia 
if ((event.other.myName=="obstacle" and self.myName=="boy") or (event.other.myName=="boy" and self.myName=="obstacle")) then
physics.pause()
display.remove(boy)
boy = nil

--rimozione suono in sottofondo 
audio.stop(playSound)
playSound=nil
--liberazione memoria
audio.dispose(playSound)

--rimozione listener dello sfondo
Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", bosco1)
Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", bosco2)
--rimozione listener terreno 
Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", terreno1)
Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", terreno2)
--rimozione listener collisioni 
Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", onCollision)
--Rimozione listener per il tap di boy
Runtime:removeEventListener("tap", boyJump)
--stoppamente generazione nuovi elementi 
timer.cancel(gameLoopTimer)
composer.gotoScene("restart",{ time=800, effect="crossFade" } )
end 
end
```

who can help me? thanks!

Comment: comment your code in English if you expect any help any own debugging attempts? this is not a debugging service. present some ideas, show what you have tried, reduce your code to a minimum.read [ask]

Comment: You didn't get help on the Solar2D forums after telling you were just doing this to pass a university course and that you didn't have any intention of learning or doing the hard work. You aren't getting much more help here either.